Date histogram to count unique users per month in a year
How can we calculate unique users per month for given year, but if user is already accounted for one month, then it should not consider in next months for respective year.
Tried date_histogram with cardinality but its counting unique users per month, and it is giving repeating counts.
Able to solve this issue with scripted_metric (map-reduce) and it is giving correct counts, but this is memory intensive and not performing for large datasets. So, want to take date_histogram approach which is quite faster in nature compared to scripts.
Query based on date_histogram,
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "monthly_counts": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "month": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "date",
                "calendar_interval": "month",
                "format": "yyyy-MM",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_users": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

Expecting an output something like in below format, below output is from scripted_metric,
"monthly_counts": {
  "value": {
    "2024-02": 4,
    "2024-01": 4,
    "2024-04": 2,
    "2024-03": 3,
    "2024-05": 1
  }
}


there is another issue from cardinality query
cardinality is aproximate and you cant findout exact counts
so should change the counts logic
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 100000  // Adjust this size based on your data
      },
      "aggs": {
        "monthly": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "calendar_interval": "month"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

You can use the query above for exact counts for each user per months but the issue is size of total users
also you can add filter for time range
(use daily index for skiping data from searches instead of running query on all indexes)
but at last you cant use any of these for your problem (handling visited) is not possible in elastic aggregations
